# Is there a good place to find WAF rules tested?

Tags: web-application, xss

I am searching evaluated WAF rules that check OWASP Top 10 and even more to have decent protection of a web infrastructure.

Comment: WAF rules will depend on the application it is protecting.

Comment: Modsec is an open-source WAF, you can check their rules https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you can't apply a generic set of WAF rules and suddenly be immune to OWASP Top 10 issues. You may find a compilation of WAF rules of known payloads for CVEs in Tomcat, or in nginx. Really though, once you patch your application you don't really need the WAF rules for CVEs that you're no longer vulnerable to.

There is value in WAF rules for [0-days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-day_(computing)); that is vulnerabilities that you have not had the opportunity to patch. I imagine there probably are security companies that offer services where you tell them which technologies you use and they will update your WAF rules the same day that a vulnerability goes public, but I imagine those services are expensive and hard to find; I'm not aware of any. This is also becoming a bit of a product recommendation, which is off-topic here.